# OpennSwan Ipsec Client with Cisco ASA/3000

Tags: cisco, ipsec, openswan

I've tried a week without any success to setup IPsec ESP authentication via a CISO ASA. This is the topology I'm trying to achieve
[image: here].

I want to connect to the network which is on the back of CISCO from the Ubuntu IPsec client machine itself. 
The Ubuntu client has only one eth0 interface.

On the CISCO both the server and the peer IP is set to the Ubuntu clients public IP.

Here are my confs:

```
ipsec.conf
============================
config setup
nat_traversal=yes
   virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0 /12,%v4:196.201.214.0/24
   oe=off
   force_keepalive=yes
   plutostderrlog=/var/log/openswan.log
   protostack=netkey
   keep_alive=60
include /etc/ipsec.d/*.conf
============================

ipsec.conf
===========================
conn scom   
    authby=secret
    auto=start
    keyexchange=ike    
    ikelifetime=28800s
    ike=3des-sha1;modp1024
    phase2alg=aes128-sha1;modp1024
    pfs=no
    type=tunnel
    aggrmode=no
    compress=no
    forceencaps=yes
    left=10.146.74.49 (INternal IP Ubuntu openswan client)
    leftid=10.146.74.49
    leftsubnet=40.127.178.200/32 (External IP ubuntu openswan client)
    leftsourceip=40.127.178.200
    leftnexthop=%defaultroute
    right=196.201.212.240 (Ciso ASA public IP)
    rightsubnets={196.201.214.xx/32,196.201.214.xpx/32,196.201.214.xax/32,196.201.214.xxx/32,196.201.214.xjx/32,196.201.214.xxy/32,196.201.214.sss/32}
```

With this config the tunnel comes UP. But actually the left IP should be the Public IP of Ubuntu openswan client right? The tunnel fails If I put the public IP as the left parameter.

If the topology I mentioned has to work, what am I missing?